# Reaching from first index to last with minimum product without using Graphs?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Solving this [problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHRL4) on codechef:

> After visiting a childhood friend, Chef wants to get back to his home.
>   Friend lives at the first street, and Chef himself lives at the N-th
>   (and the last) street. Their city is a bit special: you can move from
>   the X-th street to the Y-th street if and only if 1 <= Y - X <= K,
>   where K is the integer value that is given to you. Chef wants to get
>   to home in such a way that the product of all the visited streets'
>   special numbers is minimal (including the first and the N-th street).
>   Please, help him to find such a product. Input
>
> The first line of input consists of two integer numbers - N and K -
>   the number of streets and the value of K respectively. The second line
>   consist of N numbers - A1, A2, ..., AN respectively, where Ai equals
>   to the special number of the i-th street. Output
>
> Please output the value of the minimal possible product, modulo
>   1000000007. Constraints
>
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^5 1 ≤ K ≤ N Example
>
> Input: 4 2 1 2 3 4.
>
> Output: 8

It could be solved using **graphs** based on this [tutorial](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/37605/chrl4-editorial)
I tried to solve it without using graphs and just using **recursion** and **DP**.
My approach:

1. Take an array and calculate the min product to reach every index and store it in the respective index.
2. This could be calculated using top down approach and recursively sending index (eligible) until starting index is reached.
3. Out of all calculated values store the minimum one.
4. If it is already calculated return it else calculate.

CODE:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
 #define LI long int
 #define MAX 100009
 #define MOD 1000000007
 using namespace std;
 LI dp[MAX]={0};
 LI ar[MAX],k,orig;
 void cal(LI n)
 {
       if(n==0)
          return;
       if(dp[n]!=0)
          return;
       LI minn=MAX;
       for(LI i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
       {
          if(ar[n]-ar[i]<=k && ar[n]-ar[i]>=1)
          {
              cal(i);
              minn=(min(dp[i]*ar[n],minn))%MOD;
          }
       }
       dp[n]=minn%MOD;
       return;
 }

 int main()
 {
    LI n,i;
    scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&k);
    orig=n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       scanf("%ld",&ar[i]);
    dp[0]=ar[0];
    cal(n-1);
    if(dp[n-1]==MAX)
       printf("0");
    else printf("%ld",dp[n-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Its been 2 days and I have checked every corner cases and constraints but it still gives Wrong answer! Whats wrong with the solution?

Need Help.

Comment: Why I added the problem statement quote: links can become obsolete in time, the posts here should be relevant years from now; why make us follow a link to get the essential information when you can have it all in one place, here. Why I didn't remove the link (since I brought all the information here): attribution.

Comment: I updated my answer, and addressed all the points. You're DP approach is too costly and by using a bottom-up dp you can reach the correct complexity to pass all testcases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis**

There are many problems. Here is what I found:

1. You restrict the product to a value inferior to `100009` without reason. The product can be way higher that that (this is indeed the reason why the problem only asked the value modulo `1000000007`)
2. You restrict your moves from streets whose difference in `special number` is `K` whereas the problem statement says that you can move between any cities whose `index` difference is inferior to `K`
3. In you dynamic programming function you compute the product and store the modulo of the product. This can lead to a problem because the modulo of a big number can be lower than the modulo of a lower number. This may corrupt later computations.
4. The integral type you use, `long int`, is too short.
5. The complexity of your algorithm is too high.

From all these problems, the last one is the most serious. I fixed it by changing the whole aproach and using a better datastructure.

**1st Problem**

In your `main()` function:

```
if(dp[n-1]==MAX)
   printf("0");
```

In your `cal()` function:

```
LI minn=MAX;
```

You should replace this line with:

```
LI minn = std::numeric_limits<LI>::max();
```

Do not forget to:

```
#include <limits>
```

**2nd Problem**

```
   for(LI i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
      if(ar[n]-ar[i]<=k && ar[n]-ar[i]>=1)
      {
          . . .
      }
   }
```

You should replace the for loop condition:

```
  for(LI i=n-1;i>=n-k;i--)
```

And remove altogether the condition on the special numbers.

**3rd Problem**

You are looking for the path whose product of special numbers is the lowest. In your current setting, you compare path's product **after** having taken the modulo of the product. This is wrong, as the modulo of a higher number may become very low (for instance a path whose product is `1000000008` will have a modulo of `1` and you will choose this path, even if there is a path whose product is only `2`).

This means you should compare the real products, without taking their modulo. As these products can become very high you should take their logarithm. This will allow you to compare the products with a simple `double`. Remember that:

```
log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)
```

**4th Problem**

Use `unsigned long long`.

**5th Problem**

I fixed all these issues and submitted on codechef CHRL4. I got all but one test case accepted. The testcase not accepted was because of a timeout. This is due to the fact that your algorithm has got a complexity of `O(k*n)`.

You can achieve `O(n)` complexity using a bottom-up dynamic programming approach, instead of top-down and using a data structure that will return the minimum log value of the `k` previous streets. You can lookup `sliding window minimum algorithm` to find how to do.

**References**

- [numeric_limits::max()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)
- my own codechef CHRL4 solution: [bottom-up dp + sliding window minimum](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8638788)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it still shows WA https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8617807

Comment: @wrangler Did you fix the 3rd problem ?

Comment: I think 3rd problem will be for higher subtasks but my sol is not even passing 1st subtask.......and for MOD problem see this https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8057094. Done the same thing as mine  `D[i] = ((unsigned long long)D[index] * A[i]) % MOD;` but still it passes all subtasks.

Comment: I think prob is in the approach i applied but according to me its passing all manual test cases. Is there anything wrong in the approach?

Comment: @wrangler You didn't understand the problem with modulo. You're comparing values in the `dp` array as if you didn't take their modulo. This is wrong. In your link the author compares the `log` of the whole products, not the modulo of products. And by the way there is a fourth problem: you use `long` int instead of `long long`.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation